# creating a new project in xcode, different options than I expected

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have downloaded the latest varsion of Xcode. All the tutorials i see for creating a new ios application project, mention to create a view-based application.

But I do not see that option. Therefore, whatever I choose, next I do not see the folders mentioned later in the examples. (for example I see no resources folder in my project)

The picture I see when to create a new project is this:
[image]

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Single View Application" is the same as the good old "view-based application"

Answer (score 0):

In new X-code you won't find window based application option. If you want then select

**Empty Application** option. Also you will not find MainWindow.xib here. You have to do coding in Appdelegate file to load initial viewController.

If you select **Single view Application** as Antonio said you will have all viewControllers in a Storyboard. Which is introduced in new iOS 5.

You can create new folder and name it to resources.